# iOS: App-specific Auto Complete Text Predict/Suggestions

Tags: ios, swift

I've noticed that when I send someone a text, if I'm typing something similar to what I've typed before, my phone will suggest things I've typed more often.
Is there a way to have similar functionality but app-specific? Say I have a grocery list app and I usually prefer "granny smith apples." If I start typing apple I'd like to have an autocomplete suggestion with "granny smith apple."
In my research I've come across UITextChecker, but it says that's strictly for spell checking. And I believe UILexicon can only be used if you make a custom keyboard. Would that accomplish what I'm looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UILexicon which will match the user input -  it offers auto correction and suggestions -   You will have to modify the entries.    You have to do it yourself with your own UI and is considered supplementary.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilexicon